# How to solve inequalities of the form $ax-b\sqrt x+c<0$ where a and b and c are determined non zero real numbers?

Tags: inequality

How to solve inequalities of the form $ax-b\sqrt x+c<0$ where a and b and c are determined non zero real numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to solve inequalities of the form $at^2 +bt +c <0$?

Comment: $$Nooooooooooooo.$$

Comment: Welcome to math.se! In order to help you just let us know what you have found out so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $x$  to be real, we can write $\sqrt x=y\implies x=y^2$

So, we have  $$ay^2-by+c<0\implies a\left(y-\frac b{2a}\right)^2<\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$$

If $a>0$ the left hand side $\ge0$

So, there will be no solution if $b^2-4ca\le0$

Else $\displaystyle \left(y-\frac b{2a}\right)^2<\frac{b^2-4ca}a$

Now we know $\displaystyle z^2<d^2\iff -d<z<d$ for real $d>0$

Similarly for $a<0$